# Trying to link files with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

[image]  [image]I want to re-compile a large project into a `webpack`. I separated the small ES6 code from the file and placed it in another one. I ran the `webpack` all started fine without errors. But in the browser this severed function does not work shows console.error type

> `unexpected` string on the first line and on the first line this code is
>   `imported "./lang"`

code that connects another module. What is the reason for this problem, please help.

here is my `webpack` with a simple config `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require("path");

const config = {
    entry: "./common.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename:"bundle.js"
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

and if anyone need this one is `common.js` as i say the problem is in first line

```
import "./lang";

$('#select-country').selectize();

// --------------------------form open
$(".room-guests-count").click(function(e){
    $(".form-open").toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.form-open').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $('.form-open').hide();
});
// ---------------------language bar
$('.language').each(function () {
  $(this).find('> .select').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });
  $(this).find('.option').on('click', function () {
    $('.language > .select').html($(this).html()).next().slideUp();
  });
});
```

Comment: is there a file named `lang` with no extension in that directory?

Comment: @JaredSmith sorry but i think this isn't important :( but i check if it's help

Comment: The existence of the file webpack is trying to roll up for you doesn't matter? Wouldn't you expect an error if you try to include a file that doesn't exist? I think it does matter...

Comment: @JaredSmith I'll try change extension add .js  but it didn't help

Comment: @JaredSmith :) sorry for my english pal yeah file exist in that directory

Comment: @JaredSmith I'll added 2 images to show you the problem.watch in the question in the top.

Comment: Why are you including `common.js` on that page along with the bundle? Of course it's going to error...

Comment: @JaredSmith yup thanks that error is solved .wright youre answer i accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack is a *bundler*. It bundles all of your imports together in a file, so you don't need to include the originals. Remove `common.js` from the page.

On a side note, the reason for the error is that even in browsers with module support, the script tag must have `type="module"` set to properly parse the JavaScript.